Copy data from Excel to a new Word doc on a Mac
I have written Office 365, Excel VBA code to copy data from Excel to a new Word doc.
The code works on a Windows PC.
On an Apple Mac it locks up on the .Paste command.
I have since added two tests for OS type.
One for the App Binding (not sure if needed but there in case) but do not know what to use for the Apple Mac syntax.
The other at the current point of failure for the .Paste statement.
How do I resolve the Mac syntax?
I temporarily put in Msg test rows through the macro to identify where it was failing on the Mac.  It got to the row before the .Paste statement but did not get to a msg after the .Paste.
Sub WriteToWord() 

    'Which Operating System is this Macro being run on 
    Dim OSname As String 
    OSname = Application.OperatingSystem 
    If InStr(1, OSname, "windows", vbTextCompare) Then 
        OStype = 1  'ie Windows OS 
    Else 
        OStype = 2  'ie Mac OS 
    End If 
     
    If OStype = 1 Then  ' ie Winidows OS 

        'Application Binding - Late 
        Dim wdApp As Object 
        Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application") 
    Else    ' ie MAC OS 
       ' This needs to be updated for MacOS if it is different from Windows or remove the If test

    End If 

    ' Set variables 
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook 
    Set wsPISDetail = Sheets("PIS Detail") 
    Set wsPISWordLoad = Sheets("PIS Word Load") 
    PISRow = 0 
    colA = 1 
    colB = 2 
    colP = 16      

    'Get the PIS Response ROW to write to Word Document 
    PISRow = Application.InputBox("Enter the Row Number to Write to MS Word")      

    'Get PIS Response Data 
    wsPISDetail.Select 
    Range(Cells(PISRow, colA), Cells(PISRow, colP)).Select 
    Application.CutCopyMode = False 
    Selection.Copy 
    wsPISWordLoad.Select 
    Range(Cells(1, colB), Cells(16, colB)).Select 
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _ 
        False, Transpose:=True 
    Set PISData = wsPISWordLoad.Range("A1:B16")     

    'Create and Write to the new Word Document 
    With wdApp 
        .Visible = True 
        .Activate        
        Set wdDoc = .documents.Add        

        With .Selection 
            .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphLeft 
            .Font.Size = 11 
            .TypeParagraph         

            If OStype = 1 Then  ' ie Winidows OS 
            PISData.Copy 
            .Paste 
            Else    ' ie MAC OS 
            ' MacStuff 
            ' before i put this IF test in, it is the .Paste statement above that fails on MacOS 
            End If             

        'Header 
            With wdDoc.Sections(1).Headers(1).Range 
                .Font.Name = "Arial" 
                .Font.Size = 14 
                .Font.Bold = True 
                .InsertAfter Text:="Header 1 text stuff)" 
                .InsertAfter vbNewLine 
                .InsertAfter vbNewLine 
                .Font.Name = "Arial" 
                .Font.Size = 12 
                .InsertAfter Text:="Header 2 text stuff" 
                .Font.Bold = False 
            End With         

        'Footer 
            Set PISOrgName = wsPISWordLoad.Range("B1") 
            With wdDoc.Sections(1).Footers(1).Range 
                .InsertAfter PISOrgName 
                .InsertAfter vbTab 
                .InsertAfter vbTab 
                .InsertAfter Text:="Page " 
                .Fields.Add Range:=.Characters.Last, Text:="PAGE", PreserveFormatting:=False 
                .InsertAfter Text:=" of " 
                .Fields.Add Range:=.Characters.Last, Text:="NUMPAGES", PreserveFormatting:=False 
              End With 
        End With 
    End With 

'When the macro ends take the cursor to this Worksheet 
    With wsPISDetail 
        .Select 
    Range("A2").Activate 
    End With 

End Sub


I/O operations (Open, Save, Copy, Paste, etc. often require commands to pause the code so it doesn't operate faster than the operating system can handle. Do a search on VBA Wait Sleep DoEvents to find sample code.

Thanks for the suggestions. I will look into the sandboxing possibilities and potential delays in the code execution.

FWIW I can't get .Paste, or any of the .Paste variants (.PasteSpecial etc.) to work on the current version of Mac Excel/Word. If you search in StackOverflow for
[ms-word] [excel] [macOS] Paste

you will find several suggestions, one of which may work for you. This seems to be one of a set of problems related to using cross-application Automation on Mac. More about this below.
My current "solution" to this, which is not very well tested and currently not very robust, is to put a macro in Word's Normal template to do the Paste, and use Word's Application.Run method to run it. i.e. you create a new Module in Normal.dotm (in Word's VB Editor) and create a Sub mypaste() in there. Originally I tried
Sub mypaste()
Selection.Paste
End Sub

Then in Excel, instead of
With wdApp
.
.
  With.Selection
  .
  .
    .Paste

you do
With wdApp
.
.
  With.Selection
  .
  .
  End With
  .Run "mypaste"

Except that even that hangs up. So, I tried running the .Paste asynchronously, like this:
Sub mypaste()
Application.OnTime Date + (Timer + 0.1) / 86400#, "myRealpaste"
End Sub

Sub myRealPaste()
Application.Selection.Paste
End Sub

That does actually seem to work. Which suggests that the problem has something to do with Excel copying and pasting on the same thread. (In essence, the Application.OnTime starts a new Thread, then just carries on, so nothing Excel VBA has called is actually doing the Paste.)
It would be advisable to put a small delay in your Excel code immediately after the .Run "mypaste" . There are several ways to do that, and I leave you to research it.
Normal.dotm is not a good place to store any macro but in this case I haven't yet worked out how to put the same code in some kind of Addin, load it and call it.
A couple of other completely unrelated comments on your code:

If you want, you should be able to use the compile-time constants and
compile-time #If block to determine which operating system your code
is running under, e.g.
#If Mac Then
OSType = 2
#Else
OSType = 2
#End If


(Or don't bother setting an OSType variable and just surround the relevant code blocks with #If blocks)

It's a good idea to declare variables such as wdDoc, and Set their values to Nothing when you're done with them.

Finally, AFAICS Microsoft have never visibly responded to any message I have ever seen on this topic. Not unusual for them, but it does make me wonder whether their developers know how to configure MacOS to avoid this kind of problem and in fact have forgotten that they had to do so, and so have never told the rest of us. If so, possibly something to do with sandboxing. At one time I even tried setting up my entire system with the US versions of Mac and MS software in case that was the secret ingredient, but apparently not. Or maybe this stuff behaves worse on Apple silicon (I have a small M1 Mac mini here).

Thanks for the suggestions. I will look into the sandboxing possibilities and potential delays in the code execution.
